# Please help me identify this old tool

Tags: tools

[image]

Could someone please help me find out what kind of tool this is?

The right arm is inscribed with (218 1/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it looks like a « 3 in 1 » to locate or align the holes in workpieces, then tap a thread and finally install a bolt with a square head.

Square head bolts tend to be for older things but not sure what industry that was designed for.

Comment: the square head is not much larger than the shank. I've seen bolts like that locking pulleys onto shafts.

Comment: @Jasen yes, you are right - seen them as well, just could not remember last night...

Comment: @Solar Mike Awesome! Could you maybe provide me with a link to such an item? (Or wikipedia article or something) I cant seem to find anything like it online...

Comment: @ProfessionalCode the tool or the bolt for the pulley? If it is the bolt then research flat belt pulleys.

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Aluminium-V-Belt-Pulley-A-Section-Single-Groove-various-sizes-from-1-1-4-to-18-/111364001345

Comment: @Solar Mike The tool if you could find anything like it, otherwise answer accepted!